# Pytest show parameter values in failure report

Tags: pytest

Sometimes `pytest -vvv` shows the parameter values at the top of the failure report, like below, but sometimes it doesn't. How do I make it show the parameter values, when it isn't happening automatically?

```
=================================================================== FAILURES ===================================================================
_____________________________________________________________ test_person[person0] _____________________________________________________________

person = Person(name='Alice', hobbies=[Hobby(title='hacking')])

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("person", PERSONS)
    def test_person(person):
>       assert person == 'foo'
E       AssertionError: assert Person(name='Alice', hobbies=[Hobby(title='hacking')]) == 'foo'

../../tmp/ids.py:25: AssertionError
```

Comment: `pytest` lists values for all test function arguments on errors. Can you give an example of not listing the args?

Comment: @hoefling [This test run](https://travis-ci.com/python-mario/mario-addons/jobs/218430364#L393)  executing [this test](https://github.com/python-mario/mario-addons/blob/pytest/tests/test_mario_addons.py#L28)

Comment: You are using `--tb=short` in `setup.cfg`, this will supersede the verbose mode and not output test arguments under some other things.